# Javascript not works on blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using a template which contains multiple javascript libraries such as bootstrap.

The template works fine when it is on my local folder, but when I transfer files to blazor structure, the packages do not work.

Here is my `index.html` structure:

```
<div id="app">
</div>

<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/plugins/custom/vis-timeline/vis-timeline.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/widgets.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/custom/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/custom/apps/chat/chat.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put all javascript libraries references before the `_framework/blazor.webassembly.js` as follows:

```
<script src="./assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/plugins/custom/vis-timeline/vis-timeline.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/widgets.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/custom/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/js/custom/apps/chat/chat.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```